# Why is OSPF packet header contains 2 authentication fields?

Tags: networking, routing

These are the OSPF header fields:

[image]

Why does it contain 2 authentication fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why does it contain 2 authentication fields?

It doesn't, the diagram is 32 bits wide. There is 1 64-bit field (shown over 2 lines in the diagram):

> **Authentication**
>
> A **64-bit** field for use by the authentication scheme.

Source [A.3.1 The OSPF packet header](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1583/103.htm)